# Pandas - Select rows based on other rows

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,3,6,8,1,4]})

df
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  3
4  6
5  8
6  1
7  4
```

And I want to select rows which are preceded by a row that contains a one:

```
selection
   A
1  2
7  4
```

Right now, I can solve this by selecting rows with ones, getting their indices, and then adding one to the indices and then using iloc:

```
df.iloc[df[df.A == 1].index + 1]
```

But I'm wondering if there is a "more pandas" way to do this.  Further, if the search was more complicated like:  select all rows preceded by a 1 and followed by a 3.  Or what if the index wasn't just integers, but timestamps. How do I express inter-row dependencies cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
df[df.shift().A == 1]
```

Comment: Perfect!  And to make more complicated searches I can just & together multiple shifts. Thanks!